# How to control errors in http.post?

Tags: angular

I have this code to save information in Firebase, it works perfectly but I need to check if it gives me any kind of error, for example that there is no internet connection.

How do I do it?

Thank's

```
saveData( data: Data ) {
   return this.http.post(`${ this.url }/dataX.json`, data)
       .pipe(
           map( res => {
             return res;
            })
         )
      ;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to check errors:

1. Receive the error in subscription section.

```
yourService.saveData(xxx).subscribe(
    (res) => {
        // Successful Response
    },
    (err) => {
        // Error handling
    }
```

2. Catch the error using `catchError` rxjs operator

```
return this.http.post(`${ this.url }/dataX.json`, data)
   .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
            // Error handling
        })
   );
```